# Packaging war file with maven

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, maven-3, war

I thought that, if my project is named my-web-application, than when I call `mvn clean install` maven first compiles to `target\my-web-application-1.0` folder and than "zips" that folder to my-web-application-1.0.war...

But as I found recently it's not how it (maybe just with default settings) works.

I'm using some 3rd party components and I'd like to modify some styles (.css) and behavior (.js) for those components, so I simply replace content in dependency jar with my modification using

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
<plugin>
```

execution example follows (it zips org folder to componentToModify.jar)

```xml
<execution>
    <id>fix</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <configuration>
        <executable>jar</executable>
        <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
        <arguments>
            <argument>-uvf</argument>
            <argument>target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/lib/componentToModify.jar</argument>
            <argument>org</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
</execution>
```

what correctly modifies the componentToModify.jar in the `target\my-web-application-1.0`, but final war doesn't contain the modifications. It seems that libs are zipped to war from local repository.

Is there some reason for such behavior and can I change it somehow?

Comment: Please try to change the `phase` to be before `package` phase, e.g. `process-test-sources`.

Comment: Can you show the full pom file cause it look weird.

Comment: @CharleeChitsuk I tried to change packge phase with process-test-sources but in this phase there is not target\my-web-application-1.0 folder yet

@khmarbaise is it weird? I just placed `<execution>` element out of `<plugin>` element for better description...

Comment: I think the idea of maven-war-overlays sounds like a better idea than using maven-exec-plugin etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely sure but would using an Overlay help here?

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html

If all else fails, you may just want to modify the 3rd party application and produce your own jar with your changes.